# CMake find Boost both x86 and x64 on same machine

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Boost compiled libraries have the same names for x86 and x64. My project uses Boost and I want it to automatically link correct Boost libraries when compiling with CMake for x64 or x86 target

My CMakeFiles.txt uses simple code

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
    coroutine context thread filesystem program_options system
)
```

My Boost is built with (MSVC2015)

```
b2 address-model=32 --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir stage
b2 address-model=64 --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir stage64
```

I have also tried "install" target and putting boost builds into separate folders

I am building my project with (Windows)

```
md build32
cd build32
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015"
cmake --build .
cd ..
```

and

```
md build
cb build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
cmake --build .
cd ..
```

x86 target is build successfull because its libraries (boost) are laying in "stage" folder that is well-known to CMake's FindBoost module

But x64 target cant be built because FindBoost uses x86 libraries of Boost for building process and does not try to use libraries from "stage64" with this error:

> D:\lib\boost_1_61_0\stage\lib\libboost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

My goal is to exlude any additional params at "Cmake" calling to build my project and I want it to automatically find correct boost libs for x86 or x64 depending on which -G param of CMAKE I am using

How can I change my CMakeFiles.txt to make it automatically find correct boost libraries?

Boost version - 1.61, MSVC 2015, CMAKE -  3.6.2 (latest and has knowledge about boost 1.61), Windows 7 x64

Comment: You may set CMake variable `BOOST_ROOT` to approprite directory (`D:\lib\boost_1_61_0\stage64`) when build project for x86_64.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, unfortunately, boost stage dir does not contain includes - only libs. So I need to set BOOST_ROOT to d:\lib\boost_1_61_0. But even if I add -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR to d:\lib\boost_1_61_0\stage64\lib - it still uses incorrect d:\lib\boost_1_61_0\stage (x86) for libs when I am building x64. It somehow hard-coded inside CMake's findboost module

Comment: Can you try manually putting the x86 libs inside `BOOST_ROOT/lib32-msvc-14.0/` and the x64 ones in `BOOST_ROOT/lib64-msvc-14.0/` and check again?

Comment: @jv_, looks like you are correct. I need remove "stage" dir and put x86 libraries somewhere else. If my boost folder contains "stage" - it uses it and does not look into BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR at all

Comment: wasthishelpful's answer seems to be better, but you may need to use `stage32` instead of just `stage`. The problem seems to be that `BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib` seems to be unconditionally added to the list of directories where CMake looks for libraries.

Comment: yes, its hard-coded here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L1370

Comment: "boost stage dir does not contain includes" -- that's because it's a staging (intermediate) directory. You need to actually *install* the result of the build to get a directory with both includes and binaries, which you can then use as `BOOST_ROOT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have `BOOST_ROOT` set somewhere in your poject, in the cache, or in an environment variable.

Looking in the [sources](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L1334), you may short-circuit find process by setting `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR`. Using [`CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html) to detect architecture:

```
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/stage64/lib
elseif(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib
endif()

find_package(...)
```

`${BOOST_ROOT}` may be replaced with `$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}`.

Comment: Boost_LIBRARY_DIR is a result of FindBoost module, it does not look at it as param. It looks into BOOST_LIBRARYDIR param. But even if I use it - no luck. If I have "stage" dir - libraries will be used from it at any case and I cant change it

Comment: `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR` is a param. Look [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L150), and [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L912). It is used to set default value for `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE`. Looking [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L1349), it is then used prior to `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `BOOST_ROOT`

Comment: Sorry for my first comment - you are completely right. I have re-tested it again after cleaning caches and it works. Thanks!